# positioning Trapcode Particular Obscuration Layer correctly

Tags: after-effects

Using Trapcode Particular, I'm trying to position an obscuration layer so that half of my particles (spherical emitter) are being seen, then I rotate it around and see the other side of the sphere of particles.  But, I can't seem to position  the emitter and the obscuration layer correctly with respect to my other 3d layers (AE classic 3d). I can see all elements in wireframe mode except the emitter and obscuration layer. Any tips or tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see in wireframe objects, which is parts of effects (like emitter), just put in the scene Null Object and parent your effect point (emitter, etc) to it. After that, to adjust your point, adjust Null Object position.

Null Objects are visible in wireframe.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks.  But, since the 3d position of the emitter is broken down into two parameters in particular, would you write an expression to follow the Position XY, and another expression to follow the Position Z?

Comment: I don't exactly remember, how it was done in Trapcode Particular... But you can try it like this.